# Update Advanced Custom Field from HTML form

Tags: php, wordpress, insert, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a custom php code to allow visitors to add content to my website by creating posts, using a form.

It works fine.

here is my PHP code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $err = array();
    $err['status'] = true;
    $output = "";

    if(empty($_POST['content'])){
        $err['status'] = false;
        $err['msg'][] = 'Le champ "Article" ne peut être vide.';
    }

    if($err['status']){

        $insert = array(

            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_title'    => htmlentities($_POST['title']),
            'post_content'  => htmlentities($_POST['content']),
            'post_category' => array(11),
            'post_author'   => 999,
            'tags_input' => htmlentities($_POST['tags']),

        );

       // $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($insert);

        if($post_id != 0){

            $user_meta_values = array(
                'pseudo'    => htmlentities($_POST['pseudo']),
                'mail'      => $_POST['mail']
            );
            $output = add_post_meta($post_id, "user_meta", json_encode($user_meta_values)) ? 'Article inséré avec succès.' : 'Une erreur est survenue lors de l\enregistrement.' ;
        }

    }

    else{
        foreach($err['msg'] as $k=>$v)
            $output .= $v . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

and my HTML form :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url().'/ajouter'; ?>">
    <p><label for="pseudo">Nom</label><input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="mail">Mail</label><input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="title">Titre</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="content">Article</label><textarea name="content" id="content" rows="10" cols="15"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="tags">Tags</label><input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="ACF_texte">ACF_texte</label><input type="text" name="ACF_texte" id="ACF_texte" value="" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="enregistrer" /></p>
</form>
```

On every posts, I have advanced custom fields. One is for example called "text_ACF". Using the same method, I would like to be abble to get text from my form, and insert it inside my Advance Custom Field (text_ACF).

something like this in my php :

```
'ACF_custom_field_name' => htmlentities($_POST['text_ACF']),
```

and in my HTML :

```
<p><label for="text_ACF">ACF_texte</label><input type="text" name="text_ACF" id="text_ACF" value="" /></p>
```

I don't know how to do it, how to refer to my advanced custom field. Can anybody help me with this ?

Thanks a lot,

And also I would like the user to be abble to upload images also, to images fields...

Comment: You should probably tag this with wordpress, unless you're using some other cms which happens  to also have `add_post_meta`.

Comment: I'm using wordpress indeed, any ideas @MarcB

Comment: ACF is only for WordPress @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to use the ACF function [**`update_field($field_key, $value, $post_id)`**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/)
In your case it would be something like:

```
update_field(
    'field_4fc5ab37e1819lol',
    htmlentities($_POST['text_ACF']), 
    $post_id
);
```

In order to find the field key, go to the *Field Group* edit screen, and click *Screen Options* on the top-right corner, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

You definitely should take a look at the official [**ACF Docs**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) for this functions, where you'll find a complete exaplanation as well as lots of examples of usge...

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works, I had to include it in my code and do some adjustements ! thanks a lot... do you know by the way how I can achieve this with an image uploader ? if you can help would be great !

Comment: @mmdwc For an Image field, you just need to the method `update_field()` with the correct value. For example, if you set the image field to return as `ID`, you need to use the function with an integer representing the id of a new attachment...